# import error type after correctly instally lidar package

Tags: python, python-3.x, lidar

Hi I'm anaconda3  with python env version 3.9.12

WWhen I install the lidar package

```
conda install -c conda-forge lidar
```

I works fine, but when I run

```
From lidar import *

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gdal: No se encontró el proceso especificado.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 29, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 565, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1173, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gdal: No se encontró el proceso especificado.

On Windows, with Python >= 3.8, DLLs are no longer imported from the PATH.
If gdalXXX.dll is in the PATH, then set the USE_PATH_FOR_GDAL_PYTHON=YES environment variable
to feed the PATH into os.add_dll_directory().
```

I was looking for the solution but I was unable to find it.

Comment: do you have gdal installed?

Comment: I'd recommend installing in a clean environment, and don't mix conda channels. see the notes for installing geopandas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72251100/3888719) - geopandas has a lot of the same installation challenges.

Comment: Qiusheng Wu has a nice [gis environment for python](https://github.com/giswqs/pygis)

Comment: "I was looking for the solution but I was unable to find it." I tried copying and pasting `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gdal` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ImportError%3A+DLL+load+failed+while+importing+_gdal), and got the linked duplicate as the first result. How did you try to look for the solution? If you found that answer before and it didn't help, why not? What did you try after reading it, and what happened?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This has nothing to do with the duplicate answer that closed the post.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado has a good point, it is best to use python gis packages in a dedicated environment.  `conda create -n gis python =3.9` then `conda activate gis` then `conda install -c conda-forge gdal lidar`