# Need help installing geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, python-module

Unable to install geopandas: I have tried YouTube videos, used the conda forge command, still no success. Pip install geopandas gives this error:

```bash
[1 lines of output]
A GAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL CONFIG environ
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
Encountered error while generating package metadata.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error installing geopandas:" A GDAL API version must be specified " in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda)

Comment: specifically I'd recommend [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72251100/3888719). Create a clean environment. Do not install anaconda and then try to install geopandas into your base env using conda-forge. If you're really struggling I'd recommend deleting your conda environment, re-installing miniconda, and then installing geopandas in a fresh env. conda does work - I use it to install geopandas all the time (truly) but it needs to be in a clean environment with consistent channels.