# geopandas read_file function causes ImportError

Tags: python, geopandas, fiona

I just got a new computer and after downloading the newest version of the anaconda distribution I tried to install geopandas and run my script.
However, the gpd.read_file command causes an ImportError.
I have been trying to reinstall everything but nothing changed.
Does anybody know how to figure this out?

```
import geopandas as gpd

path = "C:/someshapefile.shp"

gpd.read_file(path)
```

```
ImportError: The 'read_file' function requires the 'pyogrio' or
'fiona' package, but neither is installed or imports correctly.
```

Importing fiona resulted in:

```
DLL load failed while importing ogrext: The specified module could not be found.
```

Importing pyogrio resulted in:

```
No module named 'pyogrio'
```

Just installing fiona manually like this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge fiona
```

did unfortunately not work for me.

Thanks a lot!
CM

Comment: what do you mean it didn't work?

Comment: see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda/72251100#72251100). make sure to install into a new environment with no channel conflicts. if you're installing with anaconda, you might try deleting your installation and installing miniconda.

Comment: You can also try installing pyogrio instead of fiona to make it work. `conda install -c conda-forge pyogrio`

Answer (score 0):

[git issue comment](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/1043#issuecomment-1025197010)

python -m pip install git+https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona.git

working for me