# Non-greedy XPATH to get HTML before the nearest h2 node

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler

Is it possible to scrape XPATH non-greedy-ly? I mean for example I have this HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>A</p>
    <p>B</p>
    <h2>Only until this node</h2>
    <p>I should not get this</p>
    <h2>Even though this node exists</h2>
</div>
```

I want an XPATH which only gets the paragraphs with A and B inside. The text inside the nearest `h2` node is always changing, so I need non-greedy XPATH if it is possible. Is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `<h2>Only until this node</h2>` is dynamic, you can select first index of `h2`

```
//div/h2[1]/preceding-sibling::p
```

```js
var htmlString = `
<body>
  <div>
    <p>A</p>
    <p>B</p>
    <h2>Only until this node</h2>
    <p>I should not get this</p>
    <h2>Even though this node exists</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>A1</p>
    <p>B2</p>
    <p>C3</p>
    <h2>Second Only until this node</h2>
    <p>I should not get this</p>
    <h2>Even though this node exists</h2>
  </div>
</body>`;

var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/xml');
var iterator = doc.evaluate('//div/h2[1]/preceding-sibling::p', doc, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
while (thisNode) {
  console.log(thisNode.outerHTML);
  thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
}
```

Comment: Cool! You could guess what I was thinking! Yeah, the second `h2` node is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this xpath

`//div/p[following::h2[contains(.,'Only until this node')]]`

to get desired content out of the html elements until it hits the `p` element containing this text `Only until this node`.

Check out the example below:

```
from scrapy import Selector

htmldoc="""
<div>
    <p>A</p>
    <p>B</p>
    <p>C</p>
    <p>D</p>
    <h2>Only until this node</h2>
    <p>E</p>
    <p>F</p>
    <p>I should not get this</p>
    <h2>Even though this node exists</h2>
    <p>I should not even this</p>
</div>
"""
sel = Selector(text=htmldoc)
for item in sel.xpath("//div/p[following::h2[contains(.,'Only until this node')]]/text()").extract():
    print(item)
```

What it produces:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have installed Selector and I got 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy''

Comment: Is this related to specific version of python. I am using 3.7

Comment: No. Any version will do. Perhaps you need to have `twisted` installed first.

Comment: I am using pycharm and I got  errors when trying to install 'Twisted' package too .. May be the problem with the IDE? .. What is the best IDE?

Comment: Are you not using cmd to perform those installations?

Comment: I tried both pycharm and cmd ... and the same result of errors at the end of both

Comment: I have found solution at this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) In  Lalit Kumar B's comment

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
/div/p[following-sibling::*[self::h2='Only until this node']]
```

It gets all `p` elements which have a `h2` successor with the `text()` value "Only until this node".