# AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation...can't use speech Recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-c++, pyaudio

I'm trying to make a basic speech Recognition assistant. When I run the code, it tells me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mo.haytham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mo.haytham/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/ALPHA_BASIC.py", line 22, in <module>
    hear()
  File "C:/Users/Mo.haytham/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/ALPHA_BASIC.py", line 13, in hear
    with sr.Microphone() as sourse:
  File "C:\Users\Mo.haytham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "C:\Users\Mo.haytham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

I tried to `pip install pyaudio` but then this error shows up:

```
Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\mo.haytham\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MO2D8C~1.HAY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o2
10x3zl\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MO2
D8C~1.HAY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hr7kket1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\mo.haytham\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MO2D8C~1.HAY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o210x3zl\\pyaudio\\setup.p
y'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MO2D8C~1.HAY\AppData\Local\
Temp\pip-record-hr7kket1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MO2D8C~1.HAY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o210x3zl\pyaudio\
```

```
def hear():
    import speech_recognition as sr
    ear = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as sourse:
        print("listening...")
        audio = ear.listen(sourse)
        try:
            text = ear.recognize_google(audio)
            print(text)
        except:
            print("i didn't get that...")

hear()
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Terminal type

```
pip install pipwin
```

Then

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Comment: That will work in `Python 3.8.5` , i was trying to install it in latest version, that does not work .

Answer (score 10):

If you are ubuntu 18.04 user follow these steps

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev python-pyaudio
```

Then

```
pip install PyAudio
```

Comment: For ubuntu 22.04 try `sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev python3-pyaudio`

Comment: @M.R.M. solution also worked for my ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 5):

I've also found PyAudio installation can be a pain, even a deal-breaker for some end-users, because of installation difficulties.  In principle there's no reason why `speech_recognition.Recognizer.listen()` couldn't take its input from other audio libraries such as [sounddevice](https://pypi.org/project/sounddevice/) or [soundcard](https://pypi.org/project/SoundCard/) or [audiomath](https://pypi.org/project/audiomath/), all of which are usually easier to install. Luckily, although the `speech_recognition` code itself only provides PyAudio implementations, internally it requires only a few attributes of `Microphone` to be duck-typed to allow it to `listen()` successfully. Specifically:

- `source` must be an instance of a `speech_recognition.AudioSource` subclass
- `source.stream` must be non-`None` while the source is active
- `source.CHUNK` must be the (integer) number of samples per chunk
- `source.SAMPLE_RATE` must be the sampling rate
- `source.SAMPLE_WIDTH` must be the number of bytes per sample
- `source.stream.read(numberOfSamples)` must return raw single-channel audio data

Here is a duck-typed solution using [audiomath](https://pypi.org/project/audiomath/):

```
import audiomath; audiomath.RequireAudiomathVersion( '1.12.0' )
import speech_recognition  # NB: python -m pip install SpeechRecognition

class DuckTypedMicrophone( speech_recognition.AudioSource ): # descent from AudioSource is required purely to pass an assertion in Recognizer.listen()
    def __init__( self, device=None, chunkSeconds=1024/44100.0 ):  # 1024 samples at 44100 Hz is about 23 ms
        self.recorder = None
        self.device = device
        self.chunkSeconds = chunkSeconds
    def __enter__( self ):
        self.nSamplesRead = 0
        self.recorder = audiomath.Recorder( audiomath.Sound( 5, nChannels=1 ), loop=True, device=self.device )
        # Attributes required by Recognizer.listen():
        self.CHUNK = audiomath.SecondsToSamples( self.chunkSeconds, self.recorder.fs, int )
        self.SAMPLE_RATE = int( self.recorder.fs )
        self.SAMPLE_WIDTH = self.recorder.sound.nbytes
        return self
    def __exit__( self, *blx ):
        self.recorder.Stop()
        self.recorder = None
    def read( self, nSamples ):
        sampleArray = self.recorder.ReadSamples( self.nSamplesRead, nSamples )
        self.nSamplesRead += nSamples
        return self.recorder.sound.dat2str( sampleArray )
    @property
    def stream( self ): # attribute must be present to pass an assertion in Recognizer.listen(), and its value must have a .read() method
        return self if self.recorder else None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import speech_recognition as sr
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with DuckTypedMicrophone() as source:
        print('\nSay something to the %s...' % source.__class__.__name__)
        audio = r.listen(source)
    print('Got it.')
    print('\nUnderstood: "%s"\n' % r.recognize_google(audio))

    if 0: # plot and/or play back captured audio
        s = audiomath.Sound(audio.get_wav_data(), fs=audio.sample_rate, nChannels=1)
        s.Play()
        s.Plot()
```

Answer (score 4):

You are getting error of installing pyaudio because you don't have c++ building tools to install pyaudio.

For installing Mircosoft visual C++ 14.0 consider this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49986365/8227403

then, 
Install pyaudio.

if you are using jupyter notebook on anaconda prompt then

```
conda install pyaudio
```

if you are using jupyter notebook using cmd then on jupyter cell,

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pyaudio
```

if you are running python file on cmd then,

```
pip3 install pyaudio #for python3
```

Answer (score 2):

## steps to install pyaudio and portaudio on Mac M1

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
brew install portaudio --HEAD
python3 -m pip install pyaudio --global-option="build_ext" --global-option="-I/opt/homebrew/include" --global-option="-L/opt/homebrew/lib"
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are missing some required files to build `pyaudio`.

From your error log,

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build >Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

You'll need to install `Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing issue even after installing pipwin so I found the solution execute below before installing PyAudio

```
!apt install libasound2-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install libportaudio-dev (first try with this)
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev (instead use this)
later install  pyaudio (python -m pip install PyAudio)

Answer (score 0):

For your error that said download the C++ build tools, I had the same error. I the downloaded the Microsoft visual studio runtime and it didn't work. I then downloaded pycharm community edition with anaconda plugin. I downloaded anaconda, activated it and then configured a conda interpreter with conda's python.exe. I then types the following:
conda install PyAudio
And it installed everything just fine for me. I would recommend doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a `macOS` user

Install portaudio

```
brew install portaudio
```

Then install pyaudio

```
pip install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

for MacOS:

brew install portaudio

pip install pyaudio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

PyAudio is supported in Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6 (in both 32-bit and 64-bit). You probably have to install any of the above python for PyAudio to work.