# Speech recognition returns unexpected error

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio, sound-recognition

So I get an error like the following:

```py
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
        import pyaudio
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'
```

```py
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\lerconn.py", line 3, in <module>
        with spr.Microphone() as mic:
      File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
        self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
      File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
        raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
    AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

with a basic speech/sound recognition system:

```py
    import speech_recognition as spr
    with spr.Microphone() as mic:
        try:
            audin = rec.recognize_google(rec.listen(mic), language="tr-TR")
            print(audin)
        except spr.UnknownValueError:
            # response= rand(notexisterrors)
             response = "I don't currently know the word or the phrase."
            
        except spr.RequestError:
            # response = rand(reqerrors)
              response = "Some weird problems with your system."
        else:
            # response = rand(unknownerrors)
             response = "Unknown error, I don't get it."
        print(response)
```

I tried `pip install`'ing PyAudio looking at the error, but that didn't work either.

I use:
Python 3.8.5 - Text Editor(s): Notepad, Notepad++ and IDLE - OS: Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit

Feel free to ask anything. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you use to run the code? Is there a possibility it's a different Python environment than the one you ran `pip` in?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984129/attributeerror-could-not-find-pyaudio-check-installation-cant-use-speech-re

Run:
pip install pipwin
Then:
pip install PyAudio

Comment: @RandomDavis As I remember, all other "pip installed" modules I already tried works fine. But yes, there does be a possibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'`  message when trying to run your example with the `SpeechRecognition` package installed only. It seems to be working if you complement with `pipwin` and `pyaudio`.

Install by running:

```sh
pip install SpeechRecognition 
pip install pipwin   # Windows
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Then I had a small issue with finding correct mic index but this works for me:

```py
import speech_recognition as spr

rec = spr.Recognizer()

# Show all available microphones in system
for index, name in enumerate(spr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
   print("Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))

# set correct mic
i = 0

response = "It worked!"

with spr.Microphone(device_index=i) as mic: 
   audio = rec.listen(mic, phrase_time_limit=5) # 5 s timer
try:
   
   audin = rec.recognize_google(audio, language="en-US")
   print(audin) # Show result
except spr.UnknownValueError:
   response = "I don't currently know the word or the phrase "
   
except spr.RequestError:
   response = "Some weird prolems with your system."
except Exception as e:
   response = "Error:" + str(e)
   response = "There is some unknown error, dude. I don't get it. Sorry."
else:
   print(response)
```

Comment: It seems to be working, but what I wonder is if it doesn't print anything after the list of microphones - the for loop- and waits with the "|" sign blinking, which I guess means "waiting for input/loading"; is there a problem with the microphone? Like, it can't get an input from the mic., so it just keeps waiting for different values?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a familiar symtom. Try changing the mic index. The phrase_time_limit should limit the recorded sound from mic to 5 seconds, so when it is working correctly the execution should be around 5 seconds. If it couldn't find any words it should end with "It worked!". You can try removing the device_index parameter too.