# AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation in pycharm

Tags: python, pyaudio

i have already tried to install seperately by using whl file it was successfully installed but when I run the program it still gives me the error that says "AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation" so I tried using pipwin but now it tells me there is no term pipwin is not recognized but when I check the interpreter there is pyaudio now I'm out of ways to fix this can anyone help me with this problem ?

```
import speech_recognition as sr

listener = sr.Recognizer()
        try:
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                print("Listening...")
                voice = listener.listen(source)
                command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
                # command = command.lower()
                # if 'bot' in command1:
                #     command1 = command1.replace('bot', '')
                print(command)
        except:
            print("not working")
            pass
```

here as u can see everytime I run it will go to the except block so tried putting the try code in the except block too and it shows me the error that pyaudio is found what should I do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation...can't use speech Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984129/attributeerror-could-not-find-pyaudio-check-installation-cant-use-speech-re)

Comment: i did that but still cannot