# I cant install pyaudio properly, is says that its installed but programm says: AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Tags: python

This doesnt works for me because of pyadio module:(((((((
I cant install pyaudio properly, is says that its installed but  programm says: AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
Anyone can help me?

```
from gtts import gTTS
import random
import time
import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr


def listen_command():
    # obtain audio from the microphone
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Скажите вашу команду: ")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
    try:
        our_speech = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru")
        print("Вы сказали: " + our_speech)
        return our_speech
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        return "ошибка"
    except sr.RequestError:
        return "ошибка"

    # return input("Скажите вашу команду: ")


def do_this_command(message):
    message = message.lower()
    if "привет" in message:
        say_message("Привет друг!")
    elif "пока" in message:
        say_message("Пока!")
        exit()
    else:
        say_message("Команда не распознана!")


def say_message(message):
    voice = gTTS(message, lang="ru")
    file_voice_name = "_audio_" + str(time.time()) +\
                      "_" + str(random.randint(0, 100000)) + ".mp3"
    voice.save(file_voice_name)
    playsound.playsound(file_voice_name)
    print("Голосовой ассистент: " + message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        command = listen_command()
        do_this_command(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59048571/16313545), try running:

```
pip install pipwin
```

and Then

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

If you are using [ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60666220/16313545) or ubuntu-based distro, try running:

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev python-pyaudio
```

and Then

```
pip install PyAudio
```

Comment: still gives me an error: raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")