# Can't use pyaudio in SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I have been trying to use SpeechRecognition module. Here is my code

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def real_time_speech_recognition():
   recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

   with sr.Microphone() as source:
      print("Say something or press 'q' to end.")
```

However, it keep on outputting the same error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/nuntea/Documents/Vasundhara Geo technology/Voice recognition and NER/Real Time Speech recogntiion/RTSR.py", line 11, in <module> real_time_speech_recognition() File "/Users/nuntea/Documents/Vasundhara Geo technology/Voice recognition and NER/Real Time Speech recogntiion/RTSR.py", line 7, in real_time_speech_recognition with sr.Microphone() as source: File "/Users/nuntea/Documents/Vasundhara Geo technology/Voice recognition and NER/Real Time Speech recogntiion/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 80, in __init__ self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio() File "/Users/nuntea/Documents/Vasundhara Geo technology/Voice recognition and NER/Real Time Speech recogntiion/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation") AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

However, I have already install PyAudio

```
(myenv) nuntea@Zonunmawias-MacBook-Air Real Time Speech recogntiion % pip list 

Package Version
certifi 2023.11.17
charset-normalizer 3.3.2
idna 3.4
keyboard 0.13.5
pip 23.3.1
PyAudio 0.2.14
requests 2.31.0
setuptools 69.0.0
SpeechRecognition 3.10.0
urllib3 2.1.0
wheel 0.41.3
```

I have tried different method mention in stackoverflow and other resources but couldn't fixed it :

```
(myenv) nuntea@Zonunmawias-MacBook-Air Real Time Speech recogntiion % xcode-select --install

xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" in System Settings to install updates

(myenv) nuntea@Zonunmawias-MacBook-Air Real Time Speech recogntiion % brew install portaudio

Warning: portaudio 19.7.0 is already installed and up-to-date. To reinstall 19.7.0, run: brew reinstall portaudio

(myenv) nuntea@Zonunmawias-MacBook-Air Real Time Speech recogntiion % pip3 install pyaudio 

Requirement already satisfied: pyaudio in ./myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.2.14)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation...can't use speech Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984129/attributeerror-could-not-find-pyaudio-check-installation-cant-use-speech-re)