# Twisted installation issue post visual studio update to 15.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-c++

Unable to install Twisted package on python 3.7 version

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio build tools 15.0 as suggested but I am still unable to install Twisted its still throwing the error "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/"

Do I need to perform any additional setup's to make it work ?

Comment: Have you actually done what the error tells you to do? Like have you installed C++ 14.0?

Comment: I could not get 14.0 but instead I installed 15.0 which should be backwards compatible right ?

Comment: yes, I think it would be backwards compatible. Sorry, but I can't help you any further (since my knowledge of this isn't that great), just thought it would be a good starting point to do what the error said. Maybe this could help: [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by downloading the wheel file from the location given below
"https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/"

Once downloaded install the wheel file use the command below to complete the installation
"pip install C:/some-dir/ wheel file name"