# pip install cx_Freeze command not working

Tags: python, pip, cx-freeze

> pip install cx_Freeze

Gives this error:-

```
Collecting cx_Freeze
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/16/eab51d6571dfec2554248cb027c51babd04d97f594ab6359e0707361297d/cx_Freeze-5.1.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: cx-Freeze
  Running setup.py install for cx-Freeze ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\alok\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Alok\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y2cpdbhl\\cx-Freeze\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Alok\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7yj276ze\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\dist.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\finder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\freezer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\hooks.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\macdist.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\main.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\setupwriter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\windist.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\ConsoleSetLibPath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\SharedLib.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\SharedLibSource.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\initscripts
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\advanced_1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\advanced_2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule\asmodule.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib\matplotlib_eg.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl\test_openpyxl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4\PyQt4app.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5\PyQt5app.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\relimport
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\relimport\relimport.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\relimport
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\relimport\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\relimport
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\service
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\Config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\service
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\ServiceHandler.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\service
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\service
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\simple
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\simple\hello.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\simple
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\simple\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\simple
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter\SimpleTkApp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\wx
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\wx\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\wx
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\wx\wxapp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\wx
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\qotd.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
    running build_ext
    building 'cx_Freeze.util' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\alok\appdata\local\programs\python\python3    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. G;__file__='"'"'C:soft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.cpdbhl\\cx-Freezenloads/                                             open)(__file__);    ----------------------------------------       ;f.close();exec(cERROR: Command "'c:\users\alok\appdata\local\prograrecord 'C:\Users\7-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize\\Users\\Alok\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"',code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"')ompile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --Alok\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7yj276ze\installngle-version-externally-managed --compile" failed win C:\Users\Alok\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y2c
```

> pip install wheel

Then downloading the cx_Freeze for python3.7 for a 32 bit system
then in that  path using cmd pip install cx_Freeze-5.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl

1.)pip install cx_Freeze

2.)pip install wheel
pip install cx_Freeze-5.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl

When i follow the link it leads to installing a .rar file when   I try running the command pip install cx_Freeze then it gives the following error,

```
  Running setup.py install for cx-Freeze ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\alok\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Alok\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5ojtpx8i\\cx-Freeze\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Alok\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9oe_iyi5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\dist.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\finder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\freezer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\hooks.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\macdist.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\main.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\setupwriter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\windist.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\ConsoleSetLibPath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\SharedLib.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\SharedLibSource.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\initscripts
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\advanced_1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\advanced_2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule\asmodule.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib\matplotlib_eg.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl\test_openpyxl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4\PyQt4app.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5\PyQt5app.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\relimport
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\relimport\relimport.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\relimport
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\relimport\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\relimport
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\service
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\Config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\service
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\ServiceHandler.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\service
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\service
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\simple
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\simple\hello.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\simple
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\simple\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\simple
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter\SimpleTkApp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\wx
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\wx\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\wx
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\wx\wxapp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\wx
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\qotd.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
    copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\setup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
    running build_ext
    building 'cx_Freeze.util' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\alok\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Alok\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5ojtpx8i\\cx-Freeze\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Alok\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9oe_iyi5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Alok\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5ojtpx8i\cx-Freeze\
```

Comment: When I follow the link

Comment: please restructure or rather structure and properly format your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 0):

you don't have Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 in your system. So first install this from official site - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

After that do below steps as -

pip install wheel

Then go to the following link to download the cx_Freeze wheel file according to you python version and windows version: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze

In your case what I can see versions as python - 3.7 and 32 bit windows system
For this you have to Download this .whl from above link -> `cx_Freeze‑5.1.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl`

Then after download save that file to any folder and in command go to that folder do as -

```
pip install cx_Freeze‑5.1.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
```

I hope this will work for you.