# Can't install mmh3 for Python3.7.1 on Win10x64 - visual C++ build tools aren't recognized

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to install `mmh3` (with some other libs) on Python  - other libs are installing OK, but `mmh3` rises an error:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\evgeniy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ppmbqvid\\mmh3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\evgeniy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6no3ekq2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'mmh3' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\evgeniy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ppmbqvid\\mmh3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\evgeniy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6no3ekq2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\evgeniy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ppmbqvid\mmh3\
```

After i got this error at first, i've installed Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 15 (v14 was installed too), checked, whether Python has its environment variables and restarted.

After restart and running `pip install -r requirements.txt` same error fires again. AND, really weird: the paths cited in the error text don't exist, both of them:

- not C:\Users\evgeniy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6no3ekq2\install-record.txt
- not C:\Users\evgeniy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ppmbqvid\mmh3\

In the folder named TEMP, which obviously exists, are no leftovers of `mmh3` install or logs or anything related.

What should i do to get `mmh3` installed?

**PS**:

- solution under https://www.scivision.dev/python-windows-visual-c-14-required/ doesn't help
- installing Python into default installation directory (AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37) doesn't help too

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to install the lib (mmh3 or any other, which makes troubles) **from within** Visual Studio.

**From within** means **from its own terminal / cmd window**, like explained in the **step 4** of [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/55575792#55575792)