# No module named 'flask_mysqldb'

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Currently i'm using python 3.74. I want to insert data in to MYSQL using 
FLASK python, but whenever i try to adding this line then error will show.
Import code is here:

`from flask_mysqldb import MySQL`

I'm using windows 10 but cannot install flask_mysqldb. Please help me to 
fix this issue.

Comment: If you have pip (which you should), `pip3 install Flask-MySQLdb`.

Comment: Whenever i try to install by using pip3 then e error will show like:  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat. This might be what you're looking for.

Comment: You need to understand that most of SQL library must be compiled to work. If you don't have the compiler, it won't work. The above a comment should help you to solve your problem.