# cx_freeze doesn't get installed in python 3.8.0

Tags: python, tkinter, cmd, exe, cx-freeze

I'm trying to install `cx_freeze` to convert my python code into an executable. But it always shows the error below.

I looked into the problem and found that I should downgrade my python version because there is no `cx_freeze` that supports Python 3.8.

**NOTE**
*It turns out that `cx_freeze` installation on Python 3.8 is possible if you download the development version directly from Git.*

```
 Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/74/a76c12e4e357c79999191d5db259e66b46c57708515395c023d38e6bbbd7/cx_Freeze-6.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: cx-freeze
 Building wheel for cx-freeze (setup.py) ... error
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
  command: 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wncuyyho\\cx-freeze\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wncuyyho\\cx-freeze\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-59n38z49' --python-tag cp38
      cwd: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wncuyyho\cx-freeze\
 Complete output (70 lines):
 running bdist_wheel
 running build
 running build_py
 creating build
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
 copying cx_Freeze\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
 copying cx_Freeze\dist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
 copying cx_Freeze\finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
 copying cx_Freeze\freezer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
 copying cx_Freeze\hooks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
 copying cx_Freeze\macdist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
 copying cx_Freeze\main.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
 copying cx_Freeze\setupwriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
 copying cx_Freeze\windist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
 copying cx_Freeze\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\initscripts
 copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\initscripts
 copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\ConsoleSetLibPath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\initscripts
 copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\SharedLib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\initscripts
 copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\SharedLibSource.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\initscripts
 copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\initscripts
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\advanced_1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\advanced_2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule\asmodule.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\importlib
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\importlib\get_examples.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\importlib
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\importlib\server_simple.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\importlib
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\importlib\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\importlib
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\importlib\web_srv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\importlib
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\importlib\wsgiserver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\importlib
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib\matplotlib_eg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl\test_openpyxl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4\PyQt4app.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5\PyQt5app.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\relimport
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\relimport\relimport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\relimport
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\relimport\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\relimport
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\service
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\Config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\service
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\ServiceHandler.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\service
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\service
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\simple
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\simple\hello.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\simple
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\simple\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\simple
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter\SimpleTkApp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\wx
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\wx\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\wx
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\wx\wxapp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\wx
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\qotd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
 copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
 running build_ext
 building 'cx_Freeze.util' extension
 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
 ----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for cx-freeze
 Running setup.py clean for cx-freeze
Failed to build cx-freeze
Installing collected packages: cx-freeze
 Running setup.py install for cx-freeze ... error
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wncuyyho\\cx-freeze\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wncuyyho\\cx-freeze\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-42p9qoxu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
        cwd: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wncuyyho\cx-freeze\
   Complete output (70 lines):
   running install
   running build
   running build_py
   creating build
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
   copying cx_Freeze\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
   copying cx_Freeze\dist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
   copying cx_Freeze\finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
   copying cx_Freeze\freezer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
   copying cx_Freeze\hooks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
   copying cx_Freeze\macdist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
   copying cx_Freeze\main.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
   copying cx_Freeze\setupwriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
   copying cx_Freeze\windist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
   copying cx_Freeze\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\initscripts
   copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\initscripts
   copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\ConsoleSetLibPath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\initscripts
   copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\SharedLib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\initscripts
   copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\SharedLibSource.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\initscripts
   copying cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\initscripts
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\advanced_1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\advanced_2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\advanced\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\advanced
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule\asmodule.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\asmodule
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\importlib
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\importlib\get_examples.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\importlib
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\importlib\server_simple.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\importlib
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\importlib\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\importlib
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\importlib\web_srv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\importlib
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\importlib\wsgiserver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\importlib
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib\matplotlib_eg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\matplotlib
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl\test_openpyxl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\openpyxl
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4\PyQt4app.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt4
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5\PyQt5app.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\PyQt5
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\relimport
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\relimport\relimport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\relimport
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\relimport\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\relimport
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\service
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\Config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\service
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\ServiceHandler.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\service
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\service\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\service
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\simple
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\simple\hello.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\simple
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\simple\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\simple
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter\SimpleTkApp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\Tkinter
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\wx
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\wx\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\wx
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\wx\wxapp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\wx
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\qotd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
   copying cx_Freeze\samples\zope\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cx_Freeze\samples\zope
   running build_ext
   building 'cx_Freeze.util' extension
   error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
   ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wncuyyho\\cx-freeze\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wncuyyho\\cx-freeze\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-42p9qoxu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: There appears to be a significant hint near the end of the output. `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

Comment: I would recommend filing bug reports for specific projects on those projects' issue trackers, not StackOverflow. Here's the one for cx_freeze: https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. This is how to solve it:

### 1. Install Visual Studio Community Edition

You need the C++ compiler for Windows 10. Download **Visual Studio 2019 Community** from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

[image]

Double click the downloaded installer. You should now see the following window (after a bit of waiting and a bit of clicking **next**):

[image]

That's the place where you should select the "things" that you want to include in your Visual Studio installation. The only thing you need right now is **Desktop development with C++**. After selecting that, you should see **Installation details** appear on the right side. There are already a few entries selected there (marked as *Automatically selected* in my screenshot above). You need to manually select the two last entries. Now click the **Install** button in the down-right corner.

Now have some patience while the installation progresses:

[image]

At the end, the installer will ask you to restart your computer. Click **OK**. That's it.

### 2. Install cx_freeze

<sub>*Just a reminder: make sure you have an updated `pip`. Issue the command:*</sub>

<sub>*`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`*</sub>

`cx_freeze` does not yet support Python 3.8. Luckily, the development version already has a fix. So you should **not** run `pip install cx_freeze`, but the following command instead:

```py
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze.git@master
```

On my computer, the installation was successfull:

```sh
C:\Users\Kristof>pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze.git@master
Collecting git+https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze.git@master
  Cloning https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze.git (to revision master) to c:\users\kristof\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-7hrolrl1
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze.git 'C:\Users\Kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-7hrolrl1'
Building wheels for collected packages: cx-Freeze
  Building wheel for cx-Freeze (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for cx-Freeze: filename=cx_Freeze-6.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl size=173005 sha256=507c3b90a1b7945fc277ccf25a5e4be7c64a37e1a1f6bce3f5171434c823fc04
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Kristof\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-p7vebfjn\wheels\30\8c\fc\66fc4c5a5e2a27aa97f29d147cee6bd5d1198260ae9d1e9102
Successfully built cx-Freeze
Installing collected packages: cx-Freeze
Successfully installed cx-Freeze-6.1
```

### 3. Install cx_freeze on Python 3.9

I came back to this question after several months. I've got `Python 3.9` now. Please note that `cx_Freeze` has changed its github path and also switched from `master` to `main` branch. This is how to install the `main` branch now:

```sh
> pip install git+https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze.git@main

Collecting git+https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze.git@main
  Cloning https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze.git (to revision main) to c:\users\gebruiker\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-ah6qsibk
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze.git 'C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ah6qsibk'
  Running command git submodule update --init --recursive -q
Requirement already satisfied: importlib_metadata>=3.1.1 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from cx-Freeze==6.6.dev0) (3.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from importlib_metadata>=3.1.1->cx-Freeze==6.6.dev0) (3.4.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: cx-Freeze
  Building wheel for cx-Freeze (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for cx-Freeze: filename=cx_Freeze-6.6.dev0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl size=260212 sha256=48855a055f9834fb666831b9ae4ff08aaa93276f9c91339614a4f58656d0bd47
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-flvt95bk\wheels\e4\58\28\02e3273cbbf0d18134fd22f6766cfdbc1b9f6b2946d5d75940
Successfully built cx-Freeze
Installing collected packages: cx-Freeze
Successfully installed cx-Freeze-6.6.dev0
```

Comment: They have changed `master` for `main`. Step 2 should be modified to: "pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze.git@main"