# Multiple Errors when installing Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for cython
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels

WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

```
b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

I followed all the step perfectly, I tried running as administrator and running a virtual environment. I'm completely lost.

Comment: You installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile i followed that link and download the first option which was vs code 2019, i don't see how that would help with the download but i tried it anyways and put it in the same directory as my kivy virtual environment folder and it still didn't work.

Comment: Well no wonder it didn’t work, it asked for version 14.0. In any case, I think this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29846087/11301900.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to Kivy downloads page you will see the supported versions of
Python from Kivy is 2.7 and 3.5 to 3.7,
so Kivy doesn't support Python 3.8 yet.
Switching to 3.7 is the only option.

[image: pic]

Comment: Thank You! I should've looked closer my bad.

Comment: I didn't even realized that my actual python is 3.8 :-/