# Can'r install kivy on PopOS and get error code 1

Tags: python, kivy

So I try to install kivy on PopOS(it's a linux distro) and I got this error

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tluj5cw5/kivy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tluj5cw5/kivy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-tluj5cw5/kivy/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-tluj5cw5/kivy/
    Complete output (672 lines):
    fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
    WARNING: Skipping page https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip because the HEAD request got Content-Type: application/zip.The only supported Content-Type is text/html
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-b_3o000g/cython/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-b_3o000g/cython/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-gjkvc12l
           cwd: /tmp/pip-wheel-b_3o000g/cython/
```

Answer (score 0):

Kivy doesn't support python 3.8 for now, please use 3.7 instead.

```
sudo dnf install python37
python3.7 -m ensurepip --default-pip --user
python3.7 -m pip install kivy --user
```

Other thread : [Multiple Errors when installing Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59295968/multiple-errors-when-installing-kivy)

Regard,