# Installing PyAudio, got error: setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Already installed Ms Visual C++, error recurs

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, pyaudio

So, I am trying to download PyAudio on Windows 10, but it displays error saying:

```
error: setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.
```

I have already installed Microsoft Visual C++ but this error keeps coming up. Is there a solution to it?

Comment: You need to install that specific version

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I did, but still, can you provide a link to a tutorial or something for this? Thanks a Lot!

Comment: Please file a bugreport. Unknown software without source ([mcve]) is not a suitable topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Make sure that when you installed it, you selected the C++ build tools. There are already a lot of related posts, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49986365/2745495.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to install it manually.

Download the Correct Pyaudio Wheel file here:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Then after installing,

open you cmd,

Then type :

pip install`{<path/to/the/whl/file>}`

Hope this works