# Cant install lxml on pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, lxml

None Of the above helped me installing lxml on pycharm.

```
It says " error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools
for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ "
```

And I still couldn't make it work. 
Please see img linked below for the error I'm getting. Any help is much appreciated thanks.

[image: error]

Comment: Do not share information is images unless absolutely necessary, which isn’t the case here. Have you done any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: I tried installing Microsoft visual c++ 14.0 seperately but it wouldnt work. would still give me the same error. by installing visual studio itself it resolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please visit
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

see down.
Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019
These Build Tools allow you to build Visual Studio projects from a command-line interface. Supported projects include: ASP.NET, Azure, C++ desktop, ClickOnce, containers, .NET Core, .NET Desktop, Node.js, Office and SharePoint, Python, TypeScript, Unit Tests, UWP, WCF, and Xamarin.

Download and install it.Then rerun python install.If you had visual studio on machine it was automatically installed.
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16