# How to resolve error while installing mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, mysql-python

I am working on a Django project and I want to connect it with MySQL. I tried the following command:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

But it is showing me the following error:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.

I installed Microsoft Visual in my PC but still, this problem occurs.

Comment: please show the full traceback

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59287503/8704316