# Failed building wheel for bottleneck error

Tags: python, cmd, installation, package

So I am trying to install bottleneck (by doing `pip install bottleneck`) in comand promt and I keep getting the error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\benito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' 'c:\users\benito\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Benito\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3cb_deoe'
       cwd: C:\Users\Benito\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hrd3bsvr\bottleneck
  Complete output (51 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck
  copying bottleneck\_pytesttester.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck
  copying bottleneck\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck
  copying bottleneck\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\benchmark
  copying bottleneck\benchmark\autotimeit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\benchmark
  copying bottleneck\benchmark\bench.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\benchmark
  copying bottleneck\benchmark\bench_detailed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\benchmark
  copying bottleneck\benchmark\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\benchmark
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\move.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\nonreduce.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\nonreduce_axis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\reduce.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\slow
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\src
  copying bottleneck\src\bn_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\src
  copying bottleneck\src\bn_template.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\src
  copying bottleneck\src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\src
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\input_modification_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\list_input_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\memory_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\move_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\nonreduce_axis_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\nonreduce_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\reduce_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\scalar_input_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\tests
  UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/_version.py
  set build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/_version.py to '1.3.1'
  running build_ext
  running config
  compiling '_configtest.c':



  int __attribute__((optimize("O3"))) have_attribute_optimize_opt_3(void*);

  int main(void)
  {
      return 0;
  }

  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bottleneck
  Running setup.py clean for bottleneck
Failed to build bottleneck
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bottleneck which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I have also installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, resset my computer and lanuched the program and done the same thing in the program and I am getting the same error. I also have done `pip install wheel` and then done `pip install bottleneck` and I recive the same error. Also I have python 3.6

Comment: How did you install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0? It seems like that's still the issue, right? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat.

Comment: Thank you so much. this worked for me, I am sorry about the confusion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem trying to install pycaret on a Windows machine. Got the error

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for bottleneck
Failed to build bottleneck
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bottleneck which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Reading the output it seams that the installation process  was unable to install bottleneck, so you have to do that manually. Pip failed doing that, so because I was using Anaconda env the conda install is the way to go. Also installing p5py and pep517 is a good idea.

I could resolve the problem with the following steps:

1. conda install bottleneck
2. pip install p5py
3. pip install pep517
4. pip install pycaret

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by installing the bottleneck manually with the respective wheel from this site: [www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/).

Simply download the file for your Python version (in my case Bottleneck‑1.3.2‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl) and install it:

```
pip install C:\Users\...
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do at first install PyPI then pyinstaller

```
pip install PyPI
pip install pyinstaller
```

PyPI installation screen capture

[image]