# Error installing pandas_profiling with Pip on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python-3.9, pandas-profiling, bottleneck

> pip install pandas_profiling

fails at

> Running setup.py install for Bottleneck ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: /home/me/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u7f_8_0k/bottleneck_1375337c49c246109b2e650965628211/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u7f_8_0k/bottleneck_1375337c49c246109b2e650965628211/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-pgrmqqqd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/me/venv/include/site/python3.9/Bottleneck
> cwd: /tmp/pip-install-u7f_8_0k/bottleneck_1375337c49c246109b2e650965628211/
> Complete output (15 lines):
> running install
> running build
> running build_py
> running build_ext
> building 'bottleneck.reduce' extension
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/bottleneck
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/bottleneck/src
> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/me/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/me/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c bottleneck/src/reduce.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/bottleneck/src/reduce.o -O2
> In file included from bottleneck/src/reduce.c:1:
> bottleneck/src/bottleneck.h:4:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
> 4 | #include <Python.h>
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.
> error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
> ----------------------------------------
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/me/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u7f_8_0k/bottleneck_1375337c49c246109b2e650965628211/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u7f_8_0k/bottleneck_1375337c49c246109b2e650965628211/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-pgrmqqqd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/me/venv/include/site/python3.9/Bottleneck Check the logs for full command output.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and my python version is-

> Python 3.9.0+

I tried installing Bottleneck separately,

> pip install Bottleneck --no-cache-dir

but that also gives the same error.  Have looked solutions to related topics,

> [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

> [setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit)

> [Failed building wheel for bottleneck error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60198432/failed-building-wheel-for-bottleneck-error)

but no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: »»fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory 4 | #include <Python.h> | «« : `sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip` ..... And the install command is : '$ **pip3 install pandas_profiling**'

Comment: Thanks @KnudLarsen; but that didn't help unfortunately.. I am already on python3-9 with pip3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. finally this is what made it work... had to install python3.9-dev.