# Errors installing packages in virtual environments in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, python-venv

I have no problems installing packages outside of virtual environments using the main system interpreter, but I keep running into errors when trying to install packages in virtual environments created by PyCharm.

First I tried installing numpy and got this error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

So I installed C++ build tools and successfully installed numpy. It might be worth noting it took a long time to install.

Then I tried installing matplotlib and got this error:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I still haven't figured that one out. Is there a single solution to all of these errors I'm running into? There's something about the virtual environments that's just broken.

Comment: did you install C++ build tools from this link ?
https://e.top4top.io/p_1517f1xje1.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: Please share the entire error message.