# Can't create conda enviroment having visual studio error

Tags: python-3.x, visual-c++, anaconda, conda

I have the following problem:
Calling

```
conda env create environment.yml
```

where .yml file contains:

```
name: my_env
dependencies:
  - pip:
      - -r file:requirements.txt
```

And I got an error

```
 Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio"
```

For almost every package I need to install.
VC++ Build tools are definetely installed and every single package from requirements.txt can be installed with either conda install or pip install without any problems whilst they can't be installed with create env as described above.
What is the problem?

Comment: Please post the full error. What does requirements.txt contain, for which package do you get the error? Which python version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)