# How do to install numpy 1.18.1 on pycharm (windows 10)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to install **numpy** package but it gives me an error, **Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required**. Tried installing Visual Studio v16.4 but still gives the same error, not sure I'm doing everything right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: Always share the entire error message. In this case, we would also need more information on your environment.