# Fail: Attempted install of twisted for scrapy with python, selinum & webdrivers to scrape angular JS websites

Tags: python, c++, web-scraping, cmd, scrapy

I have downloaded Microsoft Visual C++, using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OsGXuNA5cc after tonnes of searching around for which GB-worth of componenents I needed (and installing all and uninstalling again), So I have VS studio code and wrote a first C++ "hello world" exe file which worked to test it .

But I still getting errors on my attempted install of twisted, which is needed for Scrapy, so I can complete code with Python with seliniums (I have successfully got this) +mozzillaFireFox webdriver (I have successfully got this) for web scraping on angular tables, websites and other dynamic websites.

After

```
 py -m pip install twisted
```

in PowerShell, and CMD, ... everythings ok up to this point and i'm still getting this error : **(but as I said I have gone and got that, VS Studio Code C++).**

```
   error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-s00u5yjl\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-s00u5yjl\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-k06brtpu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Include\Twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Its all about installing scrappy which gets stuck on twisted. any help would be really appreciated.

Shutting down my PC & going for a break / fresh air . And im hoping for some help or advice when I come back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: Are you using virtual environments, or anything similar?

Comment: Thank you! Im giving that link a Go !! It looks like the solutions presented therin willl do the trick !  Life Saver !!   im just in process of downloading . No I don't think so (Virtual Env). Im not. Ill edit & let you know if it works

Comment: I don't know if it was just the downloading of of the link (C++) OR coupled of hours later downloading the latest version of twisted wheel file - and running it - but youve solved a weekend of headaches. . I have successfullly downloaded scrapy-2.0.1 . Genius @AMD thank you.