# Cannot install pip package dependencies cloned from a GitHub repo into a separate virtualenv

Tags: django, pip

I have forked and cloned a private Django GitHub repo of a friend of mine into my local directory. Since I am using Windows 8 and my friend created the repo using Linux(Ubuntu), I couldn't use his virtual env. So, I created a separate virtual environment using virtualenv(16.7.8) in my local directory. However, when I run

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

only some packages gets installed and others give error. So I had to install all the required packages by manually typing with their specific versions. However, I am unable to install two particular dependencies viz. django-compressor and rcssmin. When I ran

`pip install django-compressor==2.4`

It "*failed to build wheel for rcssmin*" and logged an error on the terminal that reads

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required ....

The full error log is shown below:

[image: full error log]

How do I solve this? Also, is there an alternative and better way to work on GitHub projects like this where I have to involve different OS(without using virtual machines to match OS)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: @hoefling I have tried `pip install --upgrade setuptools` prior to posting the question. However installing MS Visual C++ 14.0 or above requires me to upgrade to Windows 8.1 which I haven't. I will let you know once I do, if at all I do so. Thanks.