# locust is not installing on my windows 10 for load testing

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I tried installing this pip but getting some error, I want this package module for load testing
This is the output i am getting:

```
Collecting locustio
Collecting geventhttpclient-wheels==1.3.1.dev2 (from locustio)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/7f/42f8b4ac6c7ddf606fa69769cef2229a159d4af45a294053198f52586095/geventhttpclient-wheels-1.3.1.dev2.tar.gz

Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\saurabh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from geventhttpclient-wheels==1.3.1.dev2->locustio) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\saurabh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12.2; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and sys_platform == "win32"->gevent==20.4.0->locustio) (2.20)

  Running setup.py install for geventhttpclient-wheels: started
    Running setup.py install for geventhttpclient-wheels: finished with status 'error'

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\SauraBh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SauraBh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\geventhttpclient-wheels\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SauraBh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\geventhttpclient-wheels\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SauraBh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ipuoqz4r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\SauraBh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\geventhttpclient-wheels\
    Complete output (45 lines):
    C:\Users\SauraBh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:471: UserWarning: Normalizing '1.3.1dev2' to '1.3.1.dev2'
      warnings.warn(
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient
    copying src\geventhttpclient\client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient
    copying src\geventhttpclient\connectionpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient
    copying src\geventhttpclient\header.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient
    copying src\geventhttpclient\httplib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient
    copying src\geventhttpclient\response.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient
    copying src\geventhttpclient\url.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient
    copying src\geventhttpclient\useragent.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient
    copying src\geventhttpclient\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient
    running egg_info
    writing src\geventhttpclient_wheels.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\geventhttpclient_wheels.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to src\geventhttpclient_wheels.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to src\geventhttpclient_wheels.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\geventhttpclient_wheels.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'src\geventhttpclient_wheels.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    copying src\geventhttpclient\tests\oncert.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    copying src\geventhttpclient\tests\server.crt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    copying src\geventhttpclient\tests\server.key -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    copying src\geventhttpclient\tests\test_client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    copying src\geventhttpclient\tests\test_headers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    copying src\geventhttpclient\tests\test_httplib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    copying src\geventhttpclient\tests\test_keep_alive.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    copying src\geventhttpclient\tests\test_network_failures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    copying src\geventhttpclient\tests\test_no_module_ssl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    copying src\geventhttpclient\tests\test_parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    copying src\geventhttpclient\tests\test_ssl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    copying src\geventhttpclient\tests\test_url.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    copying src\geventhttpclient\tests\test_useragent.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\geventhttpclient\tests
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    building 'geventhttpclient._parser' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\SauraBh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SauraBh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\geventhttpclient-wheels\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SauraBh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\geventhttpclient-wheels\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SauraBh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ipuoqz4r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have  Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0.25 is installed in my system.
If someone knows any better tool/framework/package for testing api using python please help me. I want to check the registration api with many users at a time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Dmitri's suggestion doesnt help, you might want to try this:

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

And update to latest locust:

```
pip install -U locust
```

(Edit: locust package name is now ”locust”, not ”locustio”)

Answer (score 2):

What you need is not Visual Studio, you need [**Visual C++ build tools**](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

You can install it using using [Visual Studio Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), you just need to tick the relevant box under the C++ components:

[image]

You might also be interested in [How to Run Locust with Different Users](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-run-locust-with-different-users) article