# How to solve Visual Studio problem in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, locust

I have a problem with installation of Locust in PyCharm. I have Microsoft Visual C++ already installed but it looks like PyCharm don't see it. How can I solve this problem?
In language packages I have Polish and English
[image]

```
Collecting locust
  ...

Collecting gevent>=1.5.0 (from locust)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/f3/434c06bd285ce52a859a7239b7f03d8e02d49f4f39c7cc25536f39d7e4b1/gevent-20.6.2.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Warpath\PycharmProjects\LocustLM\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Warpath\PycharmProjects\LocustLM\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\Warpath\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r93q5z32\overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- "setuptools >= 40.8.0" wheel "Cython >= 3.0a5" "cffi >= 1.12.3 ; platform_python_implementation == 'CPython'" "greenlet >= 0.4.16 ; platform_python_implementation == 'CPython'":
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/93/4860cebd5ad3ff2664ad3c966490ccb46e3b88458b2095145bca11727ca4/setuptools-47.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/23/848298cccf8e40f5bbb59009b32848a4c38f4e7f3364297ab3c3e2e2cd14/wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting Cython>=3.0a5
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/49/a1a3ebc099b1c08df3672e3a18de32a5ec95f6ab307d8c3471425e3d0859/Cython-3.0a5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting cffi>=1.12.3
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/54/3324b0c46340c31b909fcec598696aaec7ddc8c18a63f2db352562d3354c/cffi-1.14.0.tar.gz
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Warpath\PycharmProjects\LocustLM\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 489, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
      IndexError: list index out of range
  
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Warpath\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-shqoapma\cffi\setup.py", line 127, in <module>
          if sys.platform == 'win32' and uses_msvc():
        File "C:\Users\Warpath\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-shqoapma\cffi\setup.py", line 105, in uses_msvc
          return config.try_compile('#ifndef _MSC_VER\n#error "not MSVC"\n#endif')
        File "C:\Users\Warpath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 225, in try_compile
          self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
        File "C:\Users\Warpath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 132, in _compile
          self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
        File "C:\Users\Warpath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 360, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "C:\Users\Warpath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
          vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
        File "C:\Users\Warpath\PycharmProjects\LocustLM\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        File "C:\Users\Warpath\PycharmProjects\LocustLM\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 843, in __init__
        File "C:\Users\Warpath\PycharmProjects\LocustLM\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 485, in __init__
        File "C:\Users\Warpath\PycharmProjects\LocustLM\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line 492, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  
      ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Warpath\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-shqoapma\cffi\
  
  ----------------------------------------

Command "C:\Users\Warpath\PycharmProjects\LocustLM\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Warpath\PycharmProjects\LocustLM\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\Warpath\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-r93q5z32\overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- "setuptools >= 40.8.0" wheel "Cython >= 3.0a5" "cffi >= 1.12.3 ; platform_python_implementation == 'CPython'" "greenlet >= 0.4.16 ; platform_python_implementation == 'CPython'"" failed with error code 1 in None
```

Comment: also i tried to upgrade pip and installing from settings but nothing work. it happen only for Locust, I checked with eg Faker and it's ok

Comment: Which version of Visual Cpp do you have?

Comment: 14.0, as in error

Comment: Your screenshot seems to show C++ build tools (the top left item) is NOT installed. I'm just guessing because I dont know polish :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [locust is not installing on my windows 10 for load testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592069/locust-is-not-installing-on-my-windows-10-for-load-testing)