# Microsoft Visual C++ required ERROR: Failed building wheel for jep

Tags: python, c++, windows-10, python-3.7, visual-c++-2010

As others have encountered, I am getting an error trying to install jep. However, I *do* have Microsoft Visual C++ installed but I'm not sure if I have all of the correct components. I have reviewed the other iterations of this question but it seems that individual component's names have changed. Additionally I've viewed the [github](https://github.com/ninia/jep/wiki/Windows) wiki for jep and there are no setup instructions for Python3.7.

I also have my PATH variable set according to another user's suggestion but not sure if it's right:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86**

Edit: Yes, I've tried updating setuptools. Still get the error.

[image: Components I've selected for Visual Studio]

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\strip\miniconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\strip\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i3572wz7\\jep\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\strip\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i3572wz7\\jep\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\strip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-e415hkz9'
       cwd: C:\Users\strip\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i3572wz7\jep\
  Complete output (86 lines):
  numpy include found at C:\Users\strip\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running setup_java
  Using JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1
  running build_java
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\javac.exe -deprecation -d build\java -h build\include -classpath src src\main\java\jep\AbstractNDArray.java src\main\java\jep\ClassEnquirer.java src\main\java\jep\ClassList.java src\main\java\jep\DirectNDArray.java src\main\java\jep\Interpreter.java src\main\java\jep\Jep.java src\main\java\jep\JepAccess.java src\main\java\jep\JepConfig.java src\main\java\jep\JepException.java src\main\java\jep\LibraryLocator.java src\main\java\jep\MainInterpreter.java src\main\java\jep\NamingConventionClassEnquirer.java src\main\java\jep\NDArray.java src\main\java\jep\Proxy.java src\main\java\jep\PyConfig.java src\main\java\jep\Run.java src\main\java\jep\SharedInterpreter.java src\main\java\jep\SubInterpreter.java src\main\java\jep\Util.java src\main\java\jep\python\InvocationHandler.java src\main\java\jep\python\MemoryManager.java src\main\java\jep\python\PyCallable.java src\main\java\jep\python\PyObject.java src\main\java\jep\python\PyPointer.java
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\javac.exe -deprecation -d build\java\test -classpath build\java;src src\test\java\jep\test\Test.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestCloseWithThreads.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestCompiledScript.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestDefaultMethods.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestExceptionCause.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestExec.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetByteArray.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetCollectionBoxing.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetJPyObject.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetTempValue.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetWithClass.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestInvoke.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestOverload.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestPreInitVariables.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestSharedArgv.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestSharedInterpreter.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestSharedModules.java src\test\java\jep\test\TestSharedModulesThreads.java src\test\java\jep\test\closeable\TestAutoCloseable.java src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\TestNumpy.java src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\TestNumpyArrayToString.java src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\TestNumpyProdShared.java src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\example\TestNumpyGILFreeze.java src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\example\TestNumpyMemoryLeak.java src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\example\TestNumpyProdLost.java src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\example\TestScipyFreeze.java src\test\java\jep\test\synchronization\TestCrossLangSync.java src\test\java\jep\test\types\TestFieldTypes.java src\test\java\jep\test\types\TestMethodTypes.java src\test\java\jep\test\types\TestStaticFieldTypes.java src\test\java\jep\test\types\TestStaticMethodTypes.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\AbstractNDArray.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\AbstractNDArray.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\ClassEnquirer.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\ClassEnquirer.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\ClassList.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\ClassList.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\DirectNDArray.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\DirectNDArray.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\Interpreter.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\Interpreter.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\Jep.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\Jep.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\JepAccess.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\JepAccess.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\JepConfig.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\JepConfig.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\JepException.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\JepException.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\LibraryLocator.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\LibraryLocator.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\MainInterpreter.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\MainInterpreter.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\NamingConventionClassEnquirer.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\NamingConventionClassEnquirer.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\NDArray.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\NDArray.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\Proxy.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\Proxy.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\PyConfig.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\PyConfig.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\Run.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\Run.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\SharedInterpreter.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\SharedInterpreter.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\SubInterpreter.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\SubInterpreter.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\Util.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\Util.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\python\InvocationHandler.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\python\InvocationHandler.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\python\MemoryManager.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\python\MemoryManager.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\python\PyCallable.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\python\PyCallable.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\python\PyObject.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\python\PyObject.java
  copying src\main\java\jep\python\PyPointer.java to build\java\jep.src\main\java\jep\python\PyPointer.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\Test.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\Test.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestCloseWithThreads.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestCloseWithThreads.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestCompiledScript.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestCompiledScript.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestDefaultMethods.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestDefaultMethods.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestExceptionCause.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestExceptionCause.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestExec.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestExec.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetByteArray.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetByteArray.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetCollectionBoxing.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetCollectionBoxing.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetJPyObject.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetJPyObject.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetTempValue.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetTempValue.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetWithClass.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestGetWithClass.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestInvoke.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestInvoke.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestOverload.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestOverload.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestPreInitVariables.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestPreInitVariables.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestSharedArgv.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestSharedArgv.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestSharedInterpreter.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestSharedInterpreter.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestSharedModules.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestSharedModules.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\TestSharedModulesThreads.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\TestSharedModulesThreads.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\closeable\TestAutoCloseable.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\closeable\TestAutoCloseable.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\TestNumpy.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\TestNumpy.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\TestNumpyArrayToString.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\TestNumpyArrayToString.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\TestNumpyProdShared.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\TestNumpyProdShared.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\example\TestNumpyGILFreeze.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\example\TestNumpyGILFreeze.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\example\TestNumpyMemoryLeak.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\example\TestNumpyMemoryLeak.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\example\TestNumpyProdLost.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\example\TestNumpyProdLost.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\example\TestScipyFreeze.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\numpy\example\TestScipyFreeze.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\synchronization\TestCrossLangSync.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\synchronization\TestCrossLangSync.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\types\TestFieldTypes.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\types\TestFieldTypes.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\types\TestMethodTypes.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\types\TestMethodTypes.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\types\TestStaticFieldTypes.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\types\TestStaticFieldTypes.java
  copying src\test\java\jep\test\types\TestStaticMethodTypes.java to build\java\jep.test.src\test\java\jep\test\types\TestStaticMethodTypes.java
  running build_jar
  copying src/main/resources/jep/classlist_7.txt to build/java/jep
  copying src/main/resources/jep/classlist_8.txt to build/java/jep
  copying src/main/resources/jep/classlist_9.txt to build/java/jep
  copying src/main/resources/jep/classlist_10.txt to build/java/jep
  copying src/main/resources/jep/classlist_11.txt to build/java/jep
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\jar.exe -cf build/java/jep-3.9.0-sources.jar -C build/java/jep.src/main/java jep
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\jar.exe -cfe build/java/jep-3.9.0.jar jep.Run -C build/java jep
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\jar.exe -cf build/java/jep-3.9.0-test-sources.jar -C build/java/jep.test.src/test/java jep
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\jar.exe -cfe build/java/jep-3.9.0-test.jar test.jep.Test -C build/java/test jep
  running build_py
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\jep
  copying src\main\python\jep\console.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\jep
  copying src\main\python\jep\java_import_hook.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\jep
  copying src\main\python\jep\jdbc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\jep
  copying src\main\python\jep\redirect_streams.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\jep
  copying src\main\python\jep\shared_modules_hook.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\jep
  copying src\main\python\jep\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\jep
  copying src\main\python\jep\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\jep
  running build_ext
  building 'jep' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've changed my path multiple times now, upgraded setup tools, etc but still getting the error.

Comment: Have you installed the actual build tools?

Answer (score 0):

its simple, first you need to download visual studio with **desktop development with c++**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).