# how to download Flask-MySQLdb

Tags: pip, flask-mysql

I'm currently downloading Flask -MySQLdb to work on a log-in system project as a beginner, but when I tried to install it, it kept giving me this error, which I had no idea how to solve it.

```
Collecting Flask-MySQLdb
  Using cached Flask-MySQLdb-0.2.0.tar.gz (2.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in c:\users\고명수\pycharmprojects\myeongsoopython\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask-MySQLdb) (1.1.2)
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.1.tar.gz (87 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\고명수\pycharmprojects\myeongsoopython\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-MySQLdb) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in c:\users\고명수\pycharmprojects\myeongsoopython\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-MySQLdb) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\users\고명수\pycharmprojects\myeongsoopython\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-MySQLdb) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in c:\users\고명수\pycharmprojects\myeongsoopython\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-MySQLdb) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\고명수\pycharmprojects\myeongsoopython\venv\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask>=0.10->Flask-MySQLdb) (1.1.1)
Using legacy setup.py install for Flask-MySQLdb, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy setup.py install for mysqlclient, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient, Flask-MySQLdb
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: started
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: finished with status 'error'

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\고명수\PycharmProjects\MyeongsooPython\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\고명수\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\고명수\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\고명수\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_h_9brc2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\고명수\PycharmProjects\MyeongsooPython\venv\include\site\python3.8\mysqlclient'
         cwd: C:\Users\고명수\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\mysqlclient\
    Complete output (25 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
    
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\고명수\PycharmProjects\MyeongsooPython\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\고명수\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\고명수\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\고명수\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_h_9brc2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\고명수\PycharmProjects\MyeongsooPython\venv\include\site\python3.8\mysqlclient' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\고명수\PycharmProjects\MyeongsooPython\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Well, the message suggested upgrading pip to the latest version, so I tried it but it is giving me this error again.

[image]

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is and how to solve it. **Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/**

Comment: I've downloaded it and it's still not solving...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pip+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required