# Can't install new packages for Python (Python 3.9.0, Windows 10)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, package, conda

In order to upgrade and clean up, I have reset my PC and installed Windows 10. Naturally, I installed Python as I use it frequently. But when I tried to install MatPlotLib using the command "pip install matplotlib", it shows an error message colored in red:

```
    C:\Users\majkl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.2.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\majkl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ex__f7yd\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\majkl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ex__f7yd\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\majkl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-my5odhue'
         cwd: C:\Users\majkl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ex__f7yd\matplotlib\
    Complete output (248 lines):
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\majkl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1jo_3g_p'
             cwd: C:\Users\majkl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5qwibsn2\numpy
        Complete output (200 lines):
        Running from numpy source directory.
        setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
          run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
        Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
        Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
        Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
        Cythonizing sources
        blas_opt_info:
        blas_mkl_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        blis_info:
          libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_info:
          libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
        customize GnuFCompiler
        Could not locate executable g77
        Could not locate executable f77
        customize IntelVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable ifort
        Could not locate executable ifl
        customize AbsoftFCompiler
        Could not locate executable f90
        customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable DF
        customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable efl
        customize Gnu95FCompiler
        Could not locate executable gfortran
        Could not locate executable f95
        customize G95FCompiler
        Could not locate executable g95
        customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
        customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
        Could not locate executable efort
        Could not locate executable efc
        customize PGroupFlangCompiler
        Could not locate executable flang
        don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_blas_info:
          libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_blas_info:
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        accelerate_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\majkl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5qwibsn2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
            Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
            Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
            A better performance should be easily gained by switching
            Blas library.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
        blas_info:
          libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\majkl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5qwibsn2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
            the BLAS environment variable.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
        blas_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\majkl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5qwibsn2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
            the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
          NOT AVAILABLE

        non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
        lapack_opt_info:
        lapack_mkl_info:
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_lapack_info:
          libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_clapack_info:
          libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        flame_info:
          libraries flame not found in ['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_info:
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_info:
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        lapack_info:
          libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\majkl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5qwibsn2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
            the LAPACK environment variable.
          return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        lapack_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\majkl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5qwibsn2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
            the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
          return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
          NOT AVAILABLE

        numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
          FOUND:
            language = c
            define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

        c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
          warnings.warn(msg)
        running dist_info
        running build_src
        build_src
        building py_modules sources
        creating build
        creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
        creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
        creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
        building library "npymath" sources
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\majkl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1jo_3g_p' Check the logs for full command output.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\majkl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp6fv0ox8i', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.15']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\majkl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ex__f7yd\matplotlib\setup.py", line 242, in <module>
        setup(  # Finally, pass this all along to distutils to do the heavy lifting.
      File "c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 164, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 159, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 699, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 779, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1064, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1076, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 758, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "c:\users\majkl\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\\users\\majkl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\majkl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp6fv0ox8i', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.15']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.3.2]
          python: yes [3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC
                      v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]]
        platform: yes [win32]
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

It does the same for every other package I want to install. I have no idea what to do. I have already tried reinstalling pip, Python, I have tried installing the packages via conda, but I can't seem to solve the problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You always get the same error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python 3.9 is not even released for 10 days yet. As far as i see a lot of the packages are not supporting Python 3.9 yet. I think your best bet is to uninstall Python 3.9 and install Python 3.8.6.
If you want you could try the following just to make sure, but i think i won't work.

```
pip intstall pipwin
pipwin install <package name>
```

Comment: You might want to look in to the following link https://pythonspeed.com/articles/switch-python-3.9/

Comment: There are some unofficial wheels if you wanna try them [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably advisable to first go to:
https://www.python.org/downloads/

and find latest **security release** and use it.
If you scroll little bit down you see:

[image]

So at the time of writing this that is still **Python 3.7**.

And that scoll little bit more down the same page and download latest release of Python 3.7 :

[image]

Which at the time of writting as you can see is **Python 3.7.9**:

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I went back to version 3.8.6 and everything works fine. We were a little too early.

Answer (score 0):

pip install
use CMD

```
python -m pip install -U https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/master.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall and reinstall python. If it doesn't work still, you can try this command:

```
python -m pip install -U https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/master.zip
```

It will work for you. If it still doesn't work, see if you have 'pip' on your computer.

Open Windows File Explorer and paste this the

```
%appdata%
```

And then, click on AppData and go to Local > Programs > Python > Python39 > Scripts and see if you have a file names 'pip'. If you don't have it, go-to apps and programs and search Python and click modify and check 'pip'. It should work, open a new cmd and type
`pip` and see

Comment: this worked perfectly for me, if you still cant solve the issue, download the pip manually from github

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command it will definitely work:

```bash
pip install --user package
```

Just change the `package` to what you want to install like this:

```bash
pip install --user Tensorflow
```

And just use `--user` in the last and it will definitely work for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).