# Why am I getting an error when installing Pygame?

Tags: python, pandas, installation, pip, pygame

I am running the command "pip install pygame" in my cmd prompt. I have made sure python is updated and in the path directory, and so is pip. Everything is up to date and working, however whenever I try to install a library, it loads the data, then outputs a huge red error paragraph which I simply can't understand. Please help. This is the error for pygame, I get one 5x bigger when trying to install pandas.

WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...

```
Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\VBO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2g4jyemq\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\VBO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2g4jyemq\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\VBO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2g4jyemq\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\VBO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2g4jyemq\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Note: I just tried to install Selenium and it worked, I just have no idea why pandas and p ygame shoot out errors.

Comment: are you using python 3.9?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323080/

Comment: Yep. Python 3.9.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install new packages for Python (Python 3.9.0, Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323080/cant-install-new-packages-for-python-python-3-9-0-windows-10)

Comment: Thanks @CForce99, pipwin let me install it.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.9 is very new and doesn't support a lot of the libraries. Use this if you want to install any:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install <package name>
```