# Installing spacy with pip fails with code 1

Tags: python, pip, jupyter, spacy, build-dependencies

I tried installing spacy via pip (Windows 10, 64) using the following commands:
"pip install spacy"

I installed pycharm, and installed Jupyter. Part of the dependencies of the code I want to run is the package 'spacy'. I already install VS required packages for python coding (buildtools).

**Full log here (due to character limit): https://codeshare.io/axB9Lj**

Here is my error log:

```
Building wheel for cymem (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-p_v0wdjj\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-p_v0wdjj\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-wheel-41qtwf0z'
         cwd: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-p_v0wdjj\cymem\
    Complete output (32 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
    copying cymem\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
    copying cymem\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
    package init file 'cymem\tests\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem\tests
    copying cymem\tests\test_import.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem\tests
    copying cymem\cymem.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
    copying cymem\cymem.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
    copying cymem\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
    running build_ext
    building 'cymem.cymem' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\cymem
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /EHsc /Tpcymem/cymem.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\cymem/cymem.obj /Ox /EHsc
    cymem.cpp
    cymem/cymem.cpp(4501): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
    c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
    cymem/cymem.cpp(4509): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
    c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
    cymem/cymem.cpp(4519): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
    c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
    cymem/cymem.cpp(4525): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
    c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
    cymem/cymem.cpp(4969): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
    cymem/cymem.cpp(4985): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for cymem
    Running setup.py clean for cymem
    Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Created wheel for preshed: filename=preshed-3.0.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl size=114950 sha256=444f7cf69ce1c303d46a177b79796fedd0a707a25245560ad730b71e07dca64e
    Stored in directory: c:\users\james\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\69\91\d8\60f8885ae30b632af65e4953ff0936e1c7cf92da04b10e68ba
    Building wheel for murmurhash (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for murmurhash (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Created wheel for murmurhash: filename=murmurhash-1.0.2-cp39-cp39m-win_amd64.whl size=21528 sha256=790caed2d7d3a4186cfbc2094e6863109baba19af391eb2e3dd2ca75b3a33050
    Stored in directory: c:\users\james\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\3a\e7\a3\93be18dd80417794a34df5424c79b7ccf5271c5e23dc1310e0
    Building wheel for thinc (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for thinc (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Created wheel for thinc: filename=thinc-7.4.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl size=2056285 sha256=75b73278e1df996709d2eae679f2b9069046b267fde62cf3fc63d5543db2eeba
    Stored in directory: c:\users\james\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\ff\41\81\cf7575a1112cd71ccecf68f418ae2febb361cf8aa66c53d6c4
    Building wheel for blis (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for blis (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-p_v0wdjj\\blis\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-p_v0wdjj\\blis\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-wheel-nfqd18ji'
         cwd: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-p_v0wdjj\blis\
    Complete output (31 lines):
    BLIS_COMPILER? None
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis\tests
    copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\blis
    running build_ext
    c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-p_v0wdjj\blis\blis\cy.pxd
      tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
    c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-p_v0wdjj\blis\blis\py.pyx
      tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
    Processing blis\cy.pyx
    Processing blis\py.pyx
    msvc
    py_compiler msvc
    {'APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT_AUTHOR': 'Matthew Honnibal', 'LIB': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\LIB\\amd64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\LIB\\amd64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\lib\\10.0.14393.0\\ucrt\\x64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\NETFXSDK\\4.6.1\\lib\\um\\x64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\lib\\10.0.14393.0\\um\\x64;', 'VS100COMNTOOLS': 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\Tools\\', 'APPVEYOR_PROJECT_NAME': 'cython-blis', 'AVVM_DOWNLOAD_URL': 'https://appveyordownloads.blob.core.windows.net/avvm', 'GIT_LFS_PATH': 'C:\\Program Files\\Git LFS', 'MSYSTEM_CHOST': 'x86_64-pc-msys', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL': 'honnibal+gh@gmail.com', 'WINDOWSSDK_EXECUTABLEPATH_X64': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v10.0A\\bin\\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\\x64\\', 'SYSTEMROOT': 'C:\\windows', 'LASTEXITCODE': '0', 'CHOCOLATEYLASTPATHUPDATE': 'Sun Feb  3 19:40:40 2019', 'INFOPATH': 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\local\\info;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\share\\info;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\info;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\share\\info', 'SHELL': 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe', 'MSYSTEM_CARCH': 'x86_64', 'MSYS2_PATH_TYPE': 'inherit', 'MANPATH': 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\local\\man;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\share\\man;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\man;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\share\\man', 'JAVA_HOME': 'C:\\Progra~1\\Java\\jdk1.8.0', 'CI_WINDOWS': 'True', 'APPVEYOR_BUILD_AGENT_HYPERV_NIC_CONFIGURED': 'true', 'WINDOWSLIBPATH': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\UnionMetadata;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\References', 'COMSPEC': 'C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', 'WINDIR': 'C:\\windows', 'RANLIB': 'echo', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT': '8bbf4b332e237459bb8f45dc9414b3049a202939', 'VS90COMNTOOLS': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\Common7\\Tools\\', 'ENABLENUGETPACKAGERESTORE': 'true', 'SESSIONNAME': 'Console', 'CONFIG_SITE': 'C:/Program Files/Git/etc/config.site', 'HOMEDRIVE': 'C:', 'SYSTEMDRIVE': 'C:', 'HOSTNAME': 'APPVYR-WIN', 'APPVEYOR': 'True', 'FRAMEWORKVERSION64': 'v4.0.30319', 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL': '6', 'OS': 'Windows_NT', 'FSHARPINSTALLDIR': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\F#\\4.0\\Framework\\v4.0\\', 'WINDOWSSDK_EXECUTABLEPATH_X86': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v10.0A\\bin\\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\\', 'GOROOT': 'C:\\go', 'APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE': 'Visual Studio 2015', 'CI_LINUX': 'False', 'UCRTVERSION': '10.0.14393.0', 'APPVEYOR_API_URL': 'http://localhost:1033/', 'TEMP': 'C:\\Users\\appveyor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1', 'SHLVL': '1', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_NAME': 'explosion/cython-blis', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files', 'APR_ICONV_PATH': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Subversion\\iconv', 'HOMEPATH': '\\Users\\appveyor', 'VISUALSTUDIOVERSION': '14.0', 'M2_HOME': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache\\Maven', 'WINDOWSSDKDIR': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\', 'FRAMEWORKDIR64': 'c:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64', 'LOGONSERVER': '\\\\APPVYR-WIN', 'APPVEYOR_JOB_ID': 'wp7dj9edlg7t43xq', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\lib\\pkgconfig;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\share\\pkgconfig;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\lib\\pkgconfig', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_PROVIDER': 'gitHub', '_': 'C:/Python27/python', 'APPVEYOR_URL': 'https://ci.appveyor.com', 'OPENSSL_CONF': 'C:\\OpenSSL-Win32\\bin\\openssl.cfg', 'APPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\appveyor\\AppData\\Roaming', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH': 'update-blis', 'APPVEYOR_BUILD_ID': '23072639', 'WIX': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WiX Toolset v3.11\\', 'FRAMEWORKVERSION': 'v4.0.30319', 'TMP': 'C:\\Users\\appveyor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1', 'COMPUTERNAME': 'APPVYR-WIN', 'VS110COMNTOOLS': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\Common7\\Tools\\', 'WINDOWSSDKLIBVERSION': '10.0.14393.0\\', 'USERDOMAIN': 'APPVYR-WIN', 'VSSDK120INSTALL': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VSSDK\\', 'ORIGINAL_TMP': 'C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files', 'VSSDK140INSTALL': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VSSDK\\', 'HOME': 'C:\\Users\\appveyor', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'CODECONTRACTSINSTALLDIR': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Contracts\\', 'FRAMEWORK40VERSION': 'v4.0', 'MSYSTEM_PREFIX': 'C:/Program Files/Git/usr', 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE': 'x86', 'CHOCOLATEYINSTALL': 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey', 'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData', 'TMPDIR': 'C:\\Users\\appveyor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1', 'APPVEYOR_BUILD_NUMBER': '483', 'FRAMEWORKDIR': 'c:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64', 'PROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files', 'USERNAME': 'appveyor', 'CI': 'True', 'PROMPT': '$P$G', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP': '2019-03-14T13:33:06.0000000Z', 'CC': 'clang', 'USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE': 'APPVYR-WIN', 'PATHEXT': '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.CPL', 'ORIGINAL_TEMP': 'C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1', 'APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER': 'C:\\projects\\cython-blis-h674r', 'XUNIT20': 'C:\\Tools\\xUnit20', 'APPVEYOR_PROJECT_ID': '484208', 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '2', 'ERLANG_HOME': 'C:\\Program Files\\erl9.2', 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432': 'AMD64', 'PUBLIC': 'C:\\Users\\Public', 'WINDOWSSDKVERSION': '10.0.14393.0\\', 'USERPROFILE': 'C:\\Users\\appveyor', 'PSMODULEPATH': 'C:\\Users\\appveyor\\Documents\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Users\\appveyor\\Documents\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\Tools\\PowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\Tools\\PowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Program Files\\AppVeyor\\BuildAgent\\Modules;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\PowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AWS Tools\\PowerShell;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\PowerShell\\ResourceManager\\AzureResourceManager;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\PowerShell\\ServiceManagement;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\PowerShell\\Storage;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\PowerShell\\Modules;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\PowerShell\\Modules\\', 'VS140COMNTOOLS': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\Tools\\', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG': 'false', 'APPVEYOR_PROJECT_SLUG': 'cython-blis-h674r', 'LIBPATH': 'c:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\LIB\\amd64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\LIB\\amd64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\UnionMetadata;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\References;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows Kits\\10\\ExtensionSDKs\\Microsoft.VCLibs\\14.0\\References\\CommonConfiguration\\neutral;', 'ORIGINAL_PATH': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TestWindow;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\amd64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64;C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\VCPackages;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\Tools;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HTML Help Workshop;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Team Tools\\Performance Tools\\x64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Team Tools\\Performance Tools;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\x64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\x86;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v10.0A\\bin\\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\\x64;C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin;C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\msys64\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI2\\wbin;C:\\Perl\\site\\bin;C:\\Perl\\bin;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0;C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\Web Platform Installer;C:\\Tools\\GitVersion;C:\\Tools\\PsTools;C:\\Program Files\\Git LFS;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Subversion\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\110\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\Tools\\Binn\\ManagementStudio;C:\\Tools\\WebDriver;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\TypeScript\\1.4;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\PrivateAssemblies;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\wbin;C:\\Ruby193\\bin;C:\\Tools\\NUnit\\bin;C:\\Tools\\xUnit;C:\\Tools\\MSpec;C:\\Tools\\Coverity\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CMake\\bin;C:\\go\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0\\bin;C:\\Python27;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\iojs;C:\\Program Files\\iojs;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin;C:\\Tools\\NuGet;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TestWindow;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft DNX\\Dnvm;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\130\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache\\Maven\\bin;C:\\Python27\\Scripts;C:\\Tools\\NUnit3;C:\\Program Files\\Mercurial;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet;C:\\Tools\\curl\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\AWSCLI;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\SQLDB\\DAC\\140;C:\\Tools\\vcpkg;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\erl9.2\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NSIS;C:\\Tools\\Octopus;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Service Fabric\\bin\\Fabric\\Fabric.Code;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Service Fabric\\Tools\\ServiceFabricLocalClusterManager;C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Yarn\\bin;C:\\Users\\appveyor\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\6;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin;C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.dotnet\\tools;C:\\Users\\appveyor\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\bin;C:\\Users\\appveyor\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Program Files\\AppVeyor\\BuildAgent;C:\\blis\\lib', 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER': 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel', 'COMMANDPROMPTTYPE': 'Native', 'PROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)', 'PROCESSOR_REVISION': '3f02', 'MAVEN_HOME': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache\\Maven', 'PATH': 'C:\\Users\\appveyor\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\local\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\opt\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TestWindow;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\amd64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64;C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\VCPackages;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\Tools;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HTML Help Workshop;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Team Tools\\Performance Tools\\x64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Team Tools\\Performance Tools;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\x64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\x86;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v10.0A\\bin\\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\\x64;C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin;C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\msys64\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI2\\wbin;C:\\Perl\\site\\bin;C:\\Perl\\bin;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0;C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\Web Platform Installer;C:\\Tools\\GitVersion;C:\\Tools\\PsTools;C:\\Program Files\\Git LFS;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Subversion\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\110\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\Tools\\Binn\\ManagementStudio;C:\\Tools\\WebDriver;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\TypeScript\\1.4;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\PrivateAssemblies;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI\\wbin;C:\\Ruby193\\bin;C:\\Tools\\NUnit\\bin;C:\\Tools\\xUnit;C:\\Tools\\MSpec;C:\\Tools\\Coverity\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CMake\\bin;C:\\go\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0\\bin;C:\\Python27;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\iojs;C:\\Program Files\\iojs;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin;C:\\Tools\\NuGet;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TestWindow;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft DNX\\Dnvm;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\130\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache\\Maven\\bin;C:\\Python27\\Scripts;C:\\Tools\\NUnit3;C:\\Program Files\\Mercurial;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet;C:\\Tools\\curl\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\AWSCLI;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\SQLDB\\DAC\\140;C:\\Tools\\vcpkg;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\DTS\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\erl9.2\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NSIS;C:\\Tools\\Octopus;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Service Fabric\\bin\\Fabric\\Fabric.Code;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Service Fabric\\Tools\\ServiceFabricLocalClusterManager;C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Yarn\\bin;C:\\Users\\appveyor\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\6;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin;C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.dotnet\\tools;C:\\Users\\appveyor\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\bin;C:\\Users\\appveyor\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Program Files\\AppVeyor\\BuildAgent;C:\\blis\\lib;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\vendor_perl;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\core_perl', 'PROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)', 'TERM': 'cygwin', 'PS1': '\\[\\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\\007\\]\\n\\[\\033[32m\\]\\u@\\h \\[\\033[35m\\]$MSYSTEM \\[\\033[33m\\]\\w\\[\\033[36m\\]`__git_ps1`\\[\\033[0m\\]\\n$ ', 'INCLUDE': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\INCLUDE;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\ATLMFC\\INCLUDE;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.14393.0\\ucrt;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\NETFXSDK\\4.6.1\\include\\um;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.14393.0\\shared;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.14393.0\\um;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.14393.0\\winrt;', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT_MESSAGE': 'Fiddle with appveyor', 'VS120COMNTOOLS': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\Tools\\', 'NETFXSDKDIR': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\NETFXSDK\\4.6.1\\', 'VSINSTALLDIR': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\', 'PLATFORM': 'X64', 'LOCALAPPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\appveyor\\AppData\\Local', 'EXTENSIONSDKDIR': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows Kits\\10\\ExtensionSDKs', 'APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION': '1.0.483', 'APPVEYOR_REPO_SCM': 'git', 'MSYSTEM': 'MSYS', 'PROGRAMDATA': 'C:\\ProgramData', 'APPVEYOR_JOB_NUMBER': '1', 'AS': 'llvm-as', 'AR': 'llvm-ar', 'APPVEYOR_ACCOUNT_NAME': 'honnibal', 'FP_NO_HOST_CHECK': 'NO', 'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'OLDPWD': 'C:/projects/cython-blis-h674r/flame-blis', 'DXSDK_DIR': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\\', '7ZIP': '"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe"', 'PWD': 'C:/projects/cython-blis', 'CFLAGS': '-Wno-macro-redefined', 'UNIVERSALCRTSDKDIR': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\', 'VCINSTALLDIR': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\'}error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    clang -c C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-p_v0wdjj\blis\blis\_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmpirpn3e1r\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o -O3 -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.1" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\frame\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-p_v0wdjj\blis\blis\_src\include\windows-x86_64
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
    Running setup.py clean for blis
    Building wheel for srsly (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for srsly (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Created wheel for srsly: filename=srsly-1.0.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl size=181305 sha256=51351155dea7d79397e521d806304448a542fd6f8ed0b1812367b3b619dff5cd
    Stored in directory: c:\users\james\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\6d\b1\ed\f1077cbff29f5a4f4faca0cfc086d637df60443a0496956f98
  Successfully built preshed murmurhash thinc srsly
  Failed to build cymem blis
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, cython, cymem, murmurhash, preshed, numpy, blis, wasabi, srsly, catalogue, plac, tqdm, thinc
      Running setup.py install for cymem: started
      Running setup.py install for cymem: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-p_v0wdjj\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-p_v0wdjj\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-record-s4f7a1cy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-build-env-6khvafvp\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-build-env-6khvafvp\overlay\Include\cymem'
           cwd: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-p_v0wdjj\cymem\
      Complete output (10 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      package init file 'cymem\tests\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      running build_ext
      building 'cymem.cymem' extension
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
```

Comment: try this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323080/

Comment: @CForce99 this did the trick, thank you (I downgraded python)

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov yes, it was posted by CForce99 above