# Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required for python 3.9?

Tags: python, pyaudio, python-3.9, msvc14

I got this error for PyAudio;
I installed vscode,visualstudio;
still it gives the error

Comment: I just had the same problem and answered a different question with my fix for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/64508484#64508484

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)