# Getting error while pip3 install numpy ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Viswan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphwm4yx5e'
cwd: C:\Users\Viswan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pe_1r20r\numpy
Complete output (208 lines):
Running from numpy source directory.
setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
Processing numpy/random_bounded_integers.pxd.in
Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
Processing numpy/random_bounded_integers.pyx.in
Processing numpy/random_common.pyx
Processing numpy/random_generator.pyx
Processing numpy/random_mt19937.pyx
Processing numpy/random_pcg64.pyx
Processing numpy/random_philox.pyx
Processing numpy/random_sfc64.pyx
Cythonizing sources
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib', 'C:\', 'c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs', 'C:\Users\Viswan\anaconda3\Library\lib']
NOT AVAILABLE

```
blis_info:
  libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\Viswan\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\Viswan\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
customize G95FCompiler
Could not locate executable g95
customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
customize PGroupFlangCompiler
Could not locate executable flang
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\Viswan\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\Viswan\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\Viswan\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\Viswan\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

accelerate_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Viswan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pe_1r20r\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
    Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
    Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
    A better performance should be easily gained by switching
    Blas library.
  if self._calc_info(blas):
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\Viswan\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Viswan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pe_1r20r\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  if self._calc_info(blas):
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Viswan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pe_1r20r\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  if self._calc_info(blas):
  NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\Viswan\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\Viswan\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_clapack_info:
  libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\Viswan\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

flame_info:
  libraries flame not found in ['c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\Viswan\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Viswan\anaconda3\Library\lib
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Viswan\anaconda3\Library\lib
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Viswan\anaconda3\Library\lib
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Viswan\anaconda3\Library\lib
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Viswan\anaconda3\Library\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Viswan\anaconda3\Library\lib
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Viswan\anaconda3\Library\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Viswan\anaconda3\Library\lib
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\viswan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\Viswan\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Viswan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pe_1r20r\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Viswan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pe_1r20r\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  NOT AVAILABLE

numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
  FOUND:
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running dist_info
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
creating build
creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
building library "npymath" sources
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\viswan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Viswan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphwm4yx5e' Check the logs for full command output.

I am a begginer.  What is the exact issue and ho to resolve it ?

Comment: it's because c++ 14.0 is outdated :
check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Answer (score 1):

This is because you lack C++ 14.0 in your system, friend. So install it and then try again, it wouldn't show the Error.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
Use this link to download C++ 14

If it doesn't work even then, try what I've given down

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

1. Open the given above link and download the needed version of numpy. Check the version of python also. If you are using Python 3.9 in Win64, see for this

   ```
   numpy‑1.20.2+mkl‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
   ```
2. Open CMD as administrator and navigate to the directory where you installed the numpy Library
3. And then type

   ```
   pip install <name of the file you downloaded>
   ```

Here in this case

```
pip install numpy‑1.20.2+mkl‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! How does this improve upon the previous answers?

Answer (score 0):

The cause and the solution are right there:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/