# Python 3.9 Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

so I recently upgraded to Python 3.9 and when trying to install some libraries - specifically `pip install discord` - I encountered the following error:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmprrfx0262'
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qj3xz8wb\multidict
  Complete output (40 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  running egg_info
  writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\dict.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\istr.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\iter.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\pair_list.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\views.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  running build_ext
  building 'multidict._multidict' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
  Building wheel for yarl (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_na_hzow'
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qj3xz8wb\yarl
  Complete output (35 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  running egg_info
  writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  running build_ext
  building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Obviously I went to the link and downloaded the build tools and then checked the C++ part but after restarting my computer, re-installing visual studio, I am still encountering the same problem. I am wondering if there is a part in the installation process that I am missing out on or if I have messed something up.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Answer (score 3):

Try to install Visual Studio: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16, and Visual Studio C++ Build Tools: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/. The problem should be fixed.

Make sure you have version 14+.

Comment: Already have it installed, like I said, I've tried re-installing it multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open up visual studio installer and select modify build tools
2. Go to individual components and make sure C++ 2019 Redistributable Update, C++ CMake tools for Windows, MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.27), C++ AddressSanitizer (Experimental), C++ Build Tools core features, are checked.

If not check them and select modify. If you are on an ARM or ARM64 based system, replace MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.27) with the ARM or ARM64 version.

Comment: @cap, you only typed pip install discord? no arguments along with it? 
If so, then check where you have the C++ extensions installed, for me it is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools

Comment: Is it a problem that in the Visual Studio Installer - build tools is called "Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 (2)"? I would think that the "(2)" in the title may be causing some issues.

Comment: @cap Could you upload a picture to imgur and link it here?

Comment: a picture of what? Also how could I go about finding where the C++ Extensions are installed?

Comment: @cap https://imgur.com/4YkYyCg location is at the bottom of the manage section.

An image of where it says Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 (2)

I'm going yo bed now, I'll try to help you tmrw

Comment: They are at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools. Also, here is the image of the name: https://imgur.com/a/f3Sj9Eu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223922/discussion-between-cap-and-unbeatable101).