# Error during installtion of bluepy using pip 22.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip

I`m trying to install bluepy with Python3.9.10 and pip 22.2 installed.
While doing that I keep getting the following output:

```
C:\Users\User>pip3 install bluepy
Collecting bluepy
  Using cached bluepy-1.3.0.tar.gz (217 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for bluepy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: bluepy
  Running setup.py install for bluepy ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for bluepy did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      H:\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      Working dir is C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zj6bo4s8\bluepy_8c28c6c23a27424498856c30a119129d
      execute make -C ./bluepy clean
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> bluepy

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

C:\Users\User>
```

I also tried the "solution" discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64617790/15585864) comment of a similar question, but this did not work for me. I´ve also tried reinstalling python, alongside pip, even if the output from above says that it is not a problem with pip.

These are the packages I installed with the Visual Studio Installer:
[image: installed packages]

Now I don`t know what else I should try.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this github issue](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy/issues/410):

> bluepy only runs on linux

And also [The README on github](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy):

> Python interface to Bluetooth LE on Linux

This is why you are unable to install it on windows

Comment: Ohhh okay wow thank you, I was to blind again to see that it only works for linux...