# Jupyter installation requiring C++ 14.0 on Windows 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

I'm trying to install Jupyter in a Python 3.11 installation (from python.org). It errors out with `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`. I have found other similar questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64617399/python-3-9-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-or-greater-is-required)), but following the answers has not resolved the issue. How can I get Jupyter to install successfully?

Comment: python 3.11 is still new and there is still no support in jupyter for it, downgrade python to 3.10 and it will work, currently pip will try to compile jupyter from source, and you need MSVC to do that .. and it might fail even if you had MSVC because it's still not supported.

Comment: Sure enough, that did the trick. Thank you! I've been battling weird pip-related errors for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't install in 3.11 for now! Although it may be mentioned as a stable release on the [python.org site in the downloads section](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).
A stable version basically means that most of the packages/libraries should get installed easily. Jupyter being no exception.
I remember 3.7 being a popular choice of being the stable version, python 3.10 is the apparent stable version. While 3.11 is promising of being 1.25x faster than previous fastest release, it is always crucial to have a version managers like e.g. Anaconda [install Anaconda 3](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/).
Anaconda3 will make life easy for installing any open source library you want to access while working with a successfully set up Jupyter notebook. No weird lookin' pip errors now!
[Anaconda3 will give you the notebook as such (snippet from my PC)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th4Cg.jpg)
Search for the available version with `conda search python` in the 'Anaconda Prompt' that comes with installation per se.
e.g. `conda install python= 3.7.2`

Comment: I had tried Anaconda, but ran into other problems (I don't remember what they were anymore).

Comment: Follow the 'install anaconda' link in the answer, there is a step-by-step installation for any OS of choice, choose the "recommended" options for installing, jupyter notebook comes built-in! Anaconda will serve you stable versions. I've updated the answer, kindly check :)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a big enough deal for me to go through another uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Well now that you know juptyer is not supported for the latest release of python, you can install jupyter notebook over compatible versions of python anyway. cheers! :)