# Why the pip command for installing MXNET on Windows is not working/not installing properly?

Tags: python, numpy, mxnet, d2l

I was trying to install the mxnet framework for d2l, using the instructions provided in the documentation at https://d2l.ai/chapter_installation/index.html# . But for whatever reason when I run the command for the GPU version of mxnet:

`pip install mxnet-cu101==1.7.0 -f https://dist.mxnet.io/python`

the process fails after a couple of seconds, marking a ton of errors I honestly have no idea whats referencing or trying to say, I thought that maybe I had done something wrong so I ran the command for uninstalling mxnet that is provided in the documentation, however that was unnecessary because the mxnet is not installed since the error completely stops the installation of mxnet.

[Here's the log of the error in question](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15n02Md8BgOfOwqm_VJT0tx03BZScXyLc/view?usp=sharing)

As far as i understand, it has something to do with the numpy library and a compatibility issue, but im not sure if that's all or if there's something else.

Any insight or help would be appreciated

Comment: Please do not post pictures of errors, format the traceback into your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)