# I can not install salt in python

Tags: python, installation, pip, salt-stack

I get the following error when I type

```
pip install salt
```

in my console.
ERROR:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zd44wshc\\pycryptodomex_2ba5413b7c6b416499ea6e65f33b010c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zd44wshc\\pycryptodomex_2ba5413b7c6b416499ea6e65f33b010c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-to_0m4sn'
cwd: C:\Users\venoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zd44wshc\pycryptodomex_2ba5413b7c6b416499ea6e65f33b010c\
Complete output (20 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\venoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zd44wshc\pycryptodomex_2ba5413b7c6b416499ea6e65f33b010c\setup.py", line 455, in <module>
set_compiler_options(package_root, ext_modules)
File "C:\Users\venoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zd44wshc\pycryptodomex_2ba5413b7c6b416499ea6e65f33b010c\compiler_opt.py", line 341, in set_compiler_options
clang = compiler_is_clang()
File "C:\Users\venoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zd44wshc\pycryptodomex_2ba5413b7c6b416499ea6e65f33b010c\compiler_opt.py", line 251, in compiler_is_clang
return test_compilation(source, msg="clang")
File "C:\Users\venoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zd44wshc\pycryptodomex_2ba5413b7c6b416499ea6e65f33b010c\compiler_opt.py", line 82, in test_compilation
objects = compiler.compile([fname], extra_postargs=extra_cc_options)
File "c:\users\venoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 323, in compile
self.initialize()
File "c:\users\venoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 220, in initialize
vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
File "c:\users\venoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 312, in msvc14_get_vc_env
return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
File "c:\users\venoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 266, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools:
    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
Testing support for clang
```

I also get this warning at the end:

```
----------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/3c/80cfaec41c3a9d0f524fe29bca9ab22d02ac84b5bfd6e22ade97d405bdba/pycryptodomex-3.9.7.tar.gz#sha256=50163324834edd0c9ce3e4512ded3e221c969086e10fdd5d3fdcaadac5e24a78 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycryptodomex/) (requires-python:>=2.6, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am using python 3.9.1. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: What the error says, you are missing visual build tools (i.e. a compiler):Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools:
    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I installed it and also something called Cython that was missing. However now when I try to install it says:
" Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl "
when it crashes. Do you might know how to fix this?