# UserWarning: Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

While Using Python fuzzymatch library i am facing the below issue :

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fuzzywuzzy\fuzz.py:11: UserWarning: Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher. Install python-Levenshtein to remove this warning
  warnings.warn('Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher. Install python-Levenshtein to remove this warning')
```

While i am trying to install python-Levenshtein It gives the error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-Levenshtein
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)
especially the third answer by *WISAM*.

Your problem boils down to installing e.g. *Visual Studio Community 2017*
(maybe you have *Visual Studio*, but some older version).