# Troubleshooting brownie installation

Tags: chainlink

I am preparing for the chainlink bootcamp and my brownie installation seems to be ok but when I try `brownie init`I get an error, even when I run as administrator and if I specify the file. See link below for screenshot.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>brownie init C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Brownie
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.14.6 - Python development framework for Ethereum

  File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\init.py", line 31, in main
    path = project.new(args["<path>"] or ".", args["--force"], args["--force"])
  File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 583, in new
    _create_folders(project_path)
  File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 920, in _create_folders
    project_path.joinpath(path).mkdir(exist_ok=True)
  File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1313, in mkdir
    self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\Documents\\Brownie\\build'
```

[Brownie error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9asJ4.png)

Comment: Thanks for making this! Did you install it with pipx?

Comment: I used pip initially and it worked but realised as I ran the command that I probably should have used pipx. Then proceeded to run it with pipx successfully after that.

Comment: Nice work! Could you write what you did to solve this as an answer to this question?

Comment: Just to clarify, I have not solved this issue. Maybe my last message wasn't clear enough. I used pip and then used pipx but It didn't change anything and I am still getting the error above

Comment: Does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: Or does this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68395033/11969592

Answer (score 3):

This maybe silly, but I had the same problem and I solved like this: I just move to the folder where I wanted to init my project and just run: `brownie init my-projects-name` and it worked perfectly. It is important that **my-projects-name** folder *WAS NOT CREATED* before running. So maybe you can run:

```
cd C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Brownie
brownie init my-first-brownie-project
```

Answer (score 1):

As per this https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html

Brownie is depends on some dependencies

1. python3 version 3.6 or greater, python3-dev
2. ganache-cli - tested with version 6.12.2

please check this go through this documentation

Answer (score -1):

Going by the stack trace you posted, it looks like you're trying to initialise brownie a folder in a folder that does not yet exist. The `FileNotFoundError` is thrown when there are parent-folders that don't exist yet in the path (see [Python docs for mkdir here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir)), which is likely what's happening here.

I can reproduce this error by doing `brownie init ~/test-folder-that-doesn't-exist/brownie`, where brownie and test-folder-doesn't-exist both are directories that are yet to be made. but doing `brownie init ~/brownie` does work (even if brownie has not been made yet)

Hope this helps!