# Running python file with brownie

Tags: python, brownie

I dont know how to deal with this problem, probably installed wrong something, idk, looking up for yours help

[image]

```
brownie run scripts/deploy.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
  File "c:\users\tomek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "c:\users\tomek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 44, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "c:\users\tomek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 50, in connect
    rpc.launch(active["cmd"], **active["cmd_settings"])
  File "c:\users\tomek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\__init__.py", line 75, in launch
    self.process = self.backend.launch(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\tomek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\ganache.py", line 73, in launch
    return psutil.Popen(cmd_list, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=out, stderr=out)
  File "c:\users\tomek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 1312, in __init__
    self.__subproc = subprocess.Popen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\tomek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\users\tomek\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68345891/troubleshooting-brownie-installation anything here help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the ganache-cli package because brownie is relying on this, so in your terminal (after having installed nodejs LTS) type "npm install -g ganache-cli", then try again and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the truffle (npm install truffle) and I had to close the studio and open again. And now is working.