# Error when trying to Install Web3 using Python

Tags: python, pip, web3py

Trying to install web3 in Python with the pip install command, it gets to Running setup.py install for cytoolz and then fails as follows:

I have searched many articles that suggest installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 using the Build Tools for Visual Studio, which I have done.

I have also copied the rc.exe and rc.dll from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86 to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio folder.

None of these seem to have worked unfortunately.

I tried to install cytoolz on its own but it gives the same error below.

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\mcbai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-745dmcik\\cytoolz_2a8cbc08ed71439fb6f4b92d63b43a98\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-745dmcik\\cytoolz_2a8cbc08ed71439fb6f4b92d63b43a98\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tgqd_7wt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include\cytoolz'
         cwd: C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-745dmcik\cytoolz_2a8cbc08ed71439fb6f4b92d63b43a98\
    Complete output (65 lines):
    [1/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/utils.pyx
    [2/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx
    [3/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/functoolz.pyx
    [4/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx
    [5/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/recipes.pyx
    running install
    C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    running build_ext
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\cytoolz
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt" /Tccytoolz/dicttoolz.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\cytoolz/dicttoolz.obj    dicttoolz.c
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22000.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_dicttoolz build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\cytoolz/dicttoolz.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\dicttoolz.cp39-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\cytoolz\dicttoolz.cp39-win_amd64.lib   
    dicttoolz.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_dicttoolz' specified multiple times; using first specification
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\cytoolz\dicttoolz.cp39-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\cytoolz\dicttoolz.cp39-win_amd64.exp
    Generating code
    Finished generating code
    LINK : fatal error LNK1327: failure during running rc.exe
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1327
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\mcbai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-745dmcik\\cytoolz_2a8cbc08ed71439fb6f4b92d63b43a98\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mcbai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-745dmcik\\cytoolz_2a8cbc08ed71439fb6f4b92d63b43a98\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tgqd_7wt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include\cytoolz' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Also, as an alternative to compiling from source, you could grab the whl file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cytoolz)

Comment: Try installing Web3 in `virtualenv` because there might be something wrong with your system eg name conflicts with other files.

Comment: @jjoa what do you mean by virtualenv

Comment: @TheMac by `virtualenv` I mean installing `virtualenv`, creating a virtual environment, and installing Web3 in it. Look at this: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html#setup-environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: I removed anything Visual Studio related as well as build tools, reloaded VS and then installed the following build tools as per this article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55575792/1612432