# can't install pythonRLSA

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install `pythonRLSA` using `pip install pythonRLSA` but it gives me this error
`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. get it  with build tools for visual studio`

I tried to solve the issue by following these [introductions](https://exerror.com/error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-get-it-with-microsoft-visual-c-build-tools/#:%7E:text=Visual%20C%2B%2B%2014.0-,You%20just%20need%20to%20Install%20Microsoft%20Visual%20C%2B%2B%2014.0.,you%20are%20facing%20this%20error.) but didn't work

Comment: You might try reading through the answers posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/43826967#43826967

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required